# Issue with Bot Framework emulator showing a red box with "No renderer for this activity"

Tags: botframework

This is the screenshot of the problem

[image]

My bot is running just fine other than the fact that this shows up. Other people do not seem to have the same issue as me so I am assuming that this issue has nothing to do with the code base but instead is a problem with the bot framework emulator.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the bot emulator framework to no avail. Hoping that someone here can point me in the right direction on how to fix this problem!

Comment: I think this might be a bug in the new release of the emulator. What version are you using? It seems to render correctly on 4.2.1, but not on 4.3.0 which was released the other day.

Comment: More information in this issue on Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1347